# Should I use "what" or "which"?

Tags: sentence-construction

Which of the following sentences is correct?

> 1. What medicine should I take for neck pain?
> 2. Which medicine should I take for neck pain?

Answer (score 8):

The difference is simply that ***which X***? more strongly implies that the speaker *already knows the range of possible answers*. This becomes more obvious if we consider something like...

> 1: *What is your name?*
>    2: *Which is your name?*

...where #1 is a perfectly ordinary question that people ask all the time. On the other hand, #2 would *only* occur in a context where the speaker has in front of him a list of people's names, and he knows or assumes the addressee's name is somewhere on that list.

You might therefore think of this usage of ***which*** as equivalent to *what **one** out of these possibilities*.

---

Note that this isn't a "hard-and-fast" usage distinction. It's true that *my* example #2 would probably never be used unless there really was an actual list, but *OP's* example #2 could occur even if the speaker had no idea what possible medicines might be available / suitable (but he assumes the *pharmacist* has a concept of such a "list", even if it's only in his head).

I should also point out that ***which*** doesn't necessarily imply expectation of a *single* answer. OP could have asked *Which **medicines** should I take?* - either expecting to be given a "shortlist"  of products from which he might select one, or allowing for the possibility that the pharmacist might say *You should take product A for immediate pain relief, **and** product B to reduce the inflammation and actually cure the problem*.

Comment: What about *"what day?"*. We know the range is from Monday-Sunday. But I've never heard someone uses *"which day?"*

Comment: @user178049: The fact that you wrote *never heard **someone uses*** there rather than ***...anyone use*** suggests that whatever you've been hearing is either not very much English at all, or a lot of English being spoken "incorrectly" as a second language. It's true that *overall*, "what day" is more likely than "which day", but the latter is perfectly idiomatic in many contexts. It's just that *usually* we don't consider the fact of there only being 7 *possible* days as relevant. Same as facetious *What planet are you on?* isn't affected by knowing there are only 8 (9?!) "possible answers".

Comment: @user178049: I use "which day", and hear others use it, quite a lot. The context is usually where there is a small range of days/dates being considered. Remember, a "day" is not necessarily "one name out of these seven", but "one 24-hour period out of the entire span of time"!

Answer (score 4):

Both are correct. Using the first question you ask for information.

> What medicine should I take?

Using the second one you make a choice (even only meant).

> Which medicine should I take?

Comment: What do you mean by "even only meant"?

Comment: Sometimes you are only expecting to be given a choice.